# How to set visibility if data is present in the arraylist

Tags: android

I want to check whether the particular row of data is present or not in database. If data is present then set visibility mode is visible and display my first image if data is not present in database then set visibility is Invisible and display my second image.

Here is my code.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<Product> AllMenu = new ArrayList<>();
ImageLoader imageLoader;
SQLiteDatabase sqLite;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> itemlist) {
    this.context=context;
    AllMenu = itemlist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return AllMenu.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    Product tempMenu = AllMenu.get(position);
    ImageView image_path,facility1,facility_1;
    TextView name,location,desc,facility2,facility3,facility4;
    ListView listView;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpage, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    //listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myimagelist);
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fh_name);
    location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fh_loc);
    desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fh_desc);
    facility1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fh_fc1);
    facility_1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fh_fc11);
    image_path = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_all_main);

    name.setText(tempMenu.getName());
    location.setText(tempMenu.getLocation());
    desc.setText(tempMenu.getDescription());
    for(Product myPoint : AllMenu) {
            if(myPoint.getFacility1() != null && myPoint.getFacility1().contains("Pool")) {
                facility1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                facility_1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                facility_1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                facility1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            }
    }
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(tempMenu.getImage_path(),image_path);
    return view;
}}
```

All data should come from server. Please help me solve this problem. Thank You
I want to compare with my string here is "Pool" is my string in above code.
If given string == pool then set Visibile or else set Invisible.
I want to make my changes here only.

```
for(Product myPoint : AllMenu) {
        if(myPoint.getFacility1() != null && myPoint.getFacility1().contains("Pool")) {
            facility1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            facility_1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        }else {
            facility_1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            facility1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        }
}
```

Comment: why not `equalsIgnoreCase()` ?

Comment: in my database only "Pool" is fill the colom contain in table.

Comment: If data contains null then i want visibility should be Invisible in output.

Comment: When you are comparing strings please use `String.equals(Object object)`

Comment: Who i can use that..I don't now i m new android. okay Wait i will try this.

Comment: Output is remain same all array list contain only Visible means first image but some of their is null. Nothing gonna happen with them. They will also visible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use log in your code to make sure that your comparing code working and also use equalsIgnoreCase like @shark says. Like  this:

```
for(Product myPoint : AllMenu) {
   Log.d("LIST_VIEW_ADAPTER", myPoint.getFacility1());
   if(myPoint.getFacility1() != null && myPoint.getFacility1().equalsIgnoreCase("Pool")) {
     facility1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
     facility_1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
     Log.d("LIST_VIEW_ADAPTER", "facility1 contains Pool");
   }else {
     facility_1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
     facility1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
     Log.d("LIST_VIEW_ADAPTER", "facility1 no Pool!");  
   }
}
```

Check log result in android monitor and make sure that it always return "facility1 contains Pool" for the right set visibility.

I prefer to split checking 'null' value in it's own if, like this:

```
for(Product myPoint : AllMenu) {
  Log.d("LIST_VIEW_ADAPTER", myPoint.getFacility1());
  if(myPoint.getFacility1() != null) {
    if(myPoint.getFacility1().equalsIgnoreCase("Pool")) {
      facility1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
      facility_1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
      Log.d("LIST_VIEW_ADAPTER", "facility1 contains Pool");
    } else {
      facility_1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
      facility1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
      Log.d("LIST_VIEW_ADAPTER", "facility1 no Pool!");  
    }
  } else {
    // do something if null here.
     Log.d("LIST_VIEW_ADAPTER", "NULL Value!");
  }     
}
```

-- UPDATE --

You should return position value in your following code:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

To :

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Okay sir i will try your solution..Thank You

Comment: Nothing is happen with this code only first image is visible in my listview for all value.

Comment: how the log message?.
Try to set all image visibility to Invisible in your xml list item.

Comment: @yogipuranik: Read my updated answer. There is error in your code.

Comment: Thank you to all for solving this problem. Now its working correctly.

Comment: glad it help you.;)

Comment: can u help me please to solve another problem i will posted here it is[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142573/how-to-retrieve-particular-row-data-from-server-in-android]